# Google Webmaster Tools average position?

Tags: google-search-console, google-index, ranking

I see that my site's average position is 7.0 for a certain search query.

However, it is kind of impossible for now. And when I search that query, I cannot find my site even in the first 10 pages.

So is there something I misunderstood about the average position?

Comment: Maybe your website has been penalized by Google, maybe not. Give us your website URL for analyzing.

Answer (score 1):

The "average position" is the average position when you actually show up in search.  It doesn't account for the times that you don't show up in search.

There can be cases when you show up for a query, but only very rarely.  Such a situation can cause reporting like this

- Somebody has +1 your page on Google+ then your page shows up in the SERPs only to their friends
- You show up only when non-default search settings are enabled such as "safe search off" or "verbatim search".

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. But I have two interesting stats, one for keyword "sas zombie assault 3" which has 600 impressions with average pos. = 6.5, and the other "mount&blade", 110 impressions, average pos. = 4.3. These are really common terms that I do not have a chance being in the first 10 pages. So is there a fluctuation? Like, when I publish an article, when it is fresh, does google show it in the first page, then it slowly falls down?

Comment: Yes, fluctuation like that happens frequently.  Google is always testing new content in high positions for a while.  If you get tested there and a get a bunch of clicks you might stay there.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller What if Google ranks some of your keywords on page 2 and 3 instead of page 1. These would inevitably drop further as hardly anyone goes past the first page.

Comment: In the cases where you are on page 2 and 3, Google only measures your average position when a searcher visits page 2 or 3.